# Clicking right side of inserted CKEditor5 element results in extra empty element

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm trying to insert a button in CKEditor5. Most of it is working OK but when I click on the right side of an inserted element it results in an extra empty element.

Here is the YouTube video of the behavior: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXLyJcJJk00

...And some of the code to insert the View Fragment:

```
editor.model.change(writer => {
  const viewFragment = editor.data.processor.toView('<a href="' + value.url + '" class="btn btn-' + value.type.toLowerCase() + ' simple-button-plugin">' + value.text + '</a>');
  const modelFragment = editor.data.toModel(viewFragment);
  writer.model.insertContent(modelFragment);
  writer.setSelection( editor.model.document.getRoot(), 'end' );
});
```

You can see there are `&NoBreak;` ASCII characters in there.

[image: CKEditor5 empty cloned element]

Answer (score 0):

When inserting HTML into CKEditor5, the use of   (space) characters perhaps results in an extra empty element being inserted as a non breaking space. Maybe try to remove the characters from your HTML code before inserting it into the editor:

```
editor.model.change(writer => {
  const viewFragment = editor.data.processor.toView('<a href="' + value.url + '" class="btn btn-' + value.type.toLowerCase() + ' simple-button-plugin">' + value.text.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '') + '</a>');
  const modelFragment = editor.data.toModel(viewFragment);
  writer.model.insertContent(modelFragment);
  writer.setSelection( editor.model.document.getRoot(), 'end' );
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried that and different variations of it but it did not work unfortunately.